# rails How to add all the record without .each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

This code gives me many chart. I want one chart for all the users. How can I do that

```
<% User.all.each do |e| %>
      <%= pie_chart e.products.group(:name).count %>
<% end %>
```

I tried this but it's not working undefined method `products'

```
<%= pie_chart User.all.products.group(:name).count %>
```

Comment: try `<%= pie_chart User.all.map{|u| u.products.group(:name).count} %>
`

Comment: @LesNightingill it gives me a lot of undifined

Comment: what exactly is undefined? details pls

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Seems like an odd way to make a pie chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to generate a single chart for all users without using the `.each` loop, you can modify your code as follows:

```rb
<%= pie_chart User.joins(:products).group('products.name').count %>
```

The `User.joins(:products)` part performs an inner join between the `users` and `products` tables, assuming there is an association between them. This ensures that only users with associated products are included in the query.

The `.group('products.name')` part groups the results by the `name` column of the `products` table.

Finally, the `.count` method counts the occurrences of each product name within the grouped results.

With this modified code, you should get a single chart displaying the count of each product name across all users.